# At which age are ninjas revived with Edo-Tensei?

Tags: naruto

The question is easy: At which age are people, when they are revived using Edo-Tensei? Are they exactly of that age they died? Or can the user of Edo-Tensei decide, how old the ninjas are?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the Naruto Wiki page on Edo Tensei, when [summoning](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Summoning%3a_Impure_World_Reincarnation#Summoning)

> the reincarnated seem to retain any permanent body damage and physical limitations they received during their lifetime.<sup>1</sup>

I think this means that normally they would be resurrected with the age they had upon their time of death, as well as physical conditions.

However, as we know, and the page describes in the [enhancements](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Summoning%3a_Impure_World_Reincarnation#Enhancements) part, (quote follows, as is on the site)

> Kabuto can also modify his summoned fighters, as he did with Madara Uchiha. While the technique usually reincarnates the deceased at the exact state they were in at the time of their deaths, Kabuto noted that he brought Madara back in a state that was "beyond his prime"<sup>2</sup> and was reincarnated much younger than when he died an old man as well as instilling him with abilities he had acquired in his old age.

So, basically, I think that the user may perfect the Jutsu in order to obtain the results he wants, provided that he has enough skill and knowledge on the Jutsu to do it.

> Or maybe only Kabuto can do it like that.

---

<sup>1</sup> This piece of data is stated in the [Wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Summoning%3a_Impure_World_Reincarnation#Summoning), but I do not recall if it was referenced in any manga chapter, so bear that in mind.
<sup>2</sup> *Naruto* chapter 560, page 3.

Comment: According to  Naruto chapter 565, page 1 and the enhancements part, it shows that Tobi can modify it too, but this might not be on the same level with Kabuto.

Answer (score 4):

Normally they were revived at the age of their dead. But the summoner can modify this part. As found on [this](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Summoning%3a_Impure_World_Reincarnation) site:

> Kabuto can also modify his summoned fighters, as he did with Madara Uchiha. While the technique usually reincarnates the deceased at the exact state they were in at the time of their deaths, Kabuto noted that he brought Madara back in a state that was "beyond his prime" and was reincarnated much younger than when he died an old man as well as instilling him with abilities he had acquired in his old age.

Comment: Damn. It is the second time I am writing an answer and someone posts what I was going to write while I am writing it.

Comment: @JNat Maybe you aren't fast enough ;)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there haven't been cases of the revived being younger or older. They're just the age they were at the moment of death.

For example;

> when Asuma ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAjVO.jpg)) is revived by Kabuto, he looks exactly the same as when he died. It might even be they still wear the same clothes, but I haven't checked for every revived.

Comment: Madara was revived younger