# How was it possible to summon Sasori with Edo Tensei?

Tags: naruto

As we know, Sasori has

> turned his body into a puppet, with a small "core of living flesh" being the only living part of it: [image]

[This question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/612/at-which-age-are-ninjas-revived-with-edo-tensei) also states that when summoned by Edo Tensei,

> the reincarnated seem to retain any permanent body damage and physical
>   limitations they received during their lifetime.

Obviously, Sasori would fall under someone who had suffered some physical...limitations. We know that

> after being brought back by Edo Tensei, Sasori eventually was released, and vanished like any other summoned shinobi (of flesh and bones), so it clearly wasn't another puppet: [image]

So how was Kabuto able to summon Sasori? If the reincarnation retains body damage, wouldn't he only be able to reincarnate Sasori's "Living Core"? I doubt that the process of "enchanting", which Kabuto can perform, involves re-making the whole body.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although the Wiki does says that

> the reincarnated seem to retain any permanent body damage and physical limitations they received during their lifetime<sup>1</sup>

it also says that

> Kabuto can also **modify his summoned fighters** (...). While the technique usually reincarnates the deceased at the exact state they were in at the time of their deaths, Kabuto noted that he brought Madara back in a state that was "beyond his prime" and was **reincarnated much younger than when he died** an old man as well as **instilling him with abilities he had acquired in his old age**.

The best explanation (I can come up with) for this is that he was reincarnated into an earlier body, maintaining the abilities and memories acquired until the time of his death, much like Madara's reincarnation <sup>2</sup>. Although I don't think he needs to re-make the bodies of the summoned, if it meant that, it was already proven that he could do it (it was made with Madara), so it would also be possible to make it with Sasori.

---

<sup>1</sup> This piece of data is stated in the [Wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Summoning%3a_Impure_World_Reincarnation), but I do not recall if it was referenced in any manga chapter, so bear that in mind.
<sup>2</sup> *Naruto* chapter 560, page 3. Kabuto explains Madara that he brought him *beyond his prime*.

Comment: So do you mean that (to some extent) Kabuto is able to chose at which age will someone be summoned? Because after reading the "enchantments" part for the first time, I thought it is rather like "summon an old shinobi -> perform some technique, or maybe surgery -> get a young shinobi".

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: Also compare this: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/612/at-which-age-are-ninjas-revived-with-edo-tensei

Comment: The impression I get is that he is able to choose it, as a part of the Edo Tensei itself. Perhaps when he does the summoning contract for each soul he chooses it. I am not sure, but this is the impression I get. :D

Comment: @looper, I have seen that, I even linked it in my question ;)

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: OMG, I didn't see that :D.

Comment: please include manga references...

Comment: @MozenRath: I've stated my reference is the [Naruto Wiki page on Edo Tensei](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Summoning:_Impure_World_Reincarnation).

Comment: @JNat I asked for Manga references.. not wiki references. we tend to loose context where that information actually came from if we just rely on wiki references. Next thing you know we start getting unreliable references and the site credibility is hurt.

Comment: @MozenRath: I cite my references, and then it is up to the reader to trust them or not. I have no manga nor databook references. The Wiki does not cite manga nor databook references either in this specific matter. But I'll add a note on that in the answer. Also, if you think the answer is untrustworthy downvote it, as it would not be useful.

Comment: I was just trying to get more out of the same answer I guess but I strongly think that references should be from manga/anime

Answer (score 3):

Kabuto only needs small parts of a person's body to perform this jutsu, just enough DNA to transfer the soul to a new body. You can see that Sasori's core has some blood veins which will give kabuto the chance to obtain his DNA and perform the jutsu. More info from the wiki on the Impure World Reincarnation jutsu:

> To perform this technique, the user must first acquire some of the DNA
>   of the person they intend to reincarnate. Kabuto remarks that this
>   basically amounts to grave-robbing, although blood stains or organs
>   salvaged after the target's death also work.

I also think that that wiki reference is incorrect as I haven't seen proof of any of the resurrected ninjas displaying any of their injuries which they had while they were alive. However this can also be because when they are under this jutsu they are essentially immortal, regenerate quickly, have near-unlimited chakra and regrow limbs.

Answer (score 0):

Edo tensei uses corpses and puts the soul of the dead person in. In the fight between Kankuro's team and Edo Tensei Sasori and Edo Tensei Deidara, Kankuro has Sasori's puppet body and Sasori's soul is hosted in another body. The corpse which Sasori's soul is in can be seen when he crumbles away.

Comment: I've seen this somewhere online before

Answer (score -1):

I can't find good answers but it is possible that Sasori infused his chakra into his puppet body, and continuous usage of the body as his own, coupled with his own memories of the human body, might have imprinted this body into his consciousness. Well this is "mystical speculation" but it's better than a certain funny answer I found: "Plot no Jutsu".

Comment: if u cant find good answers then don't answer. btw not ur downvoter

Comment: Ok, noted. I thought there would be no other answer possible though, because I mistakenly thought that the revived Sasori was in his puppet body but apparently he was in his human body.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of comment but I was on my tablet and didn't want to type anything of length with it.  I was your downvoter and it was for the reason MozenRath gave.  Also, speculation doesn't constitute a solid answer so unless it can be backed up with references then I'd keep it out of the Q&A portion of the site.  If you'd like to speculate with other users, gather resources, and work towards an answer, chat is a great place for that.  I know there are plenty of Naruto fans on the site that could go back and forth with you for awhile on this topic (myself included).

Answer (score -3):

I'm pretty sure Sasori's soul was still inactive, hence making him practically dead, allowing edo-tensei to take place. A question however could arise such as 'How can Sasori be resurrected if Kabuto didn't have his DNA?' Maybe he got his hands on Lady Chiyo's DNA and ... 
Well, Sasori's Grandma so yeah!